# Testing VAST 2.0 Redirects to run in HTML5 using an mp4

Tags: xml, html, redirect, mp4, vast

I am working on testing two different types of videos for our site. One standard video that we take from the raw file and convert to an mp4 format (VAST xml template). And a VAST redirect that is held within a VAST Wrapper template.  I can't test the VAST wrapper template because I don't have one.  Does anyone have a VAST 2.0 redirect that returns an .mp4 media file?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of Tremor wrapper examples on the IAB site.

Check out this page:
http://www.iab.net/guidelines/508676/digitalvideo/vast/vast_xml_samples

And here is a linear wrapper:
http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast_wrapper_linear_1.xml

It redirects to an FLV in the end, but it does provide the wrapper example that you need.

Answer (score 0):

These don't have CORS headers (they far pre-date HTML5 VAST even being a consideration) so you need to load them up to a CORS-supporting server modify them to call the VASTAdTagURI on the same server